# A trivial application of Wilson's theorem to Brocard's Problem

Tags: diophantine-equations, elementary-proofs

**Proposition:** Let $W(1)$ be the set of all Wilson primes of order $1$ and suppose $n=p-1,$ where $p$ is a prime such that $p\notin W(1)$, then there are no integer solutions to the equation
$$n!+1=m^2$$.

**Proof:**

**Wilson's theorem:**
$(p-1)!\equiv-1 \pmod p \tag 1$

$$$$ Using $(1)$, we know that $(p-1)!+1=ap$ for some $a\in\mathbb{N}$.

In order for the product $ap$ to be a perfect square, $a$ must be of the form $k^2p$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

So, $(p-1)!+1=k^2p^2$

But for primes $p\notin W(1)$, $(p-1)!\not\equiv-1 \pmod {p^2}$.

Therefore, $(p-1)!+1$ cannot be represented as a square of an integer. $\square$

$$$$The above is a glaringly obvious implication (although very weak) of Wilson's theorem on Brocard's Problem. However, I cannot find any reference to it in literature. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just because this is not very interesting, as it solves the problem for very few $n$'s. Even assuming the $abc$ conjecture, the best we can prove is that there are $\gg \log x/\log \log x$ non-Wilson primes up to $x$. But it has long been known unconditionally that there are $o(x)$ solutions, by diophantine methods. Your argument is probably just so obvious that no one ever bothered to write it down.

Comment: It is true that it solves for a very few $n$. But it strikes me as a surprise that the statement that "no solution exists for any non-Wilson prime less one." is not reported even if it is obvious.